# How can I internally keep an always nullable equivalent of a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

A code example first is essential I think. I'm trying to build a view model that I will use for all properties that need dropdown controls, and this is a start:

```
public class ListProperty<TListItem, TValue>
{
    private readonly string _valuePropertyName = "Id";
    private readonly string _textPropertyName = "Name";

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<TListItem> _list;
    public ListProperty(IEnumerable<TListItem> list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }
}
```

I would like to have an underlying property for `Value` that is always nullable, so if `TValue` is a reference type, the underlying type will just be `TValue`, but when `TValue` is a value type, the underlying type must be `Nullable<TValue>`.

**MORE:** The reason I want this, is to know whether the `Value` property has been assigned to or not. To do this without my requirement would involve having to type value as `Object`, which smells bad to me.

Comment: ? is the "Nullable" flag, i just forget where to put it :-(  pretty sure it's ?TValue when you go to construct TValue

Comment: @MattWestlake: It would be `TValue?`.  Also, @ProfK, changing types is usually a bad idea.  How about a new class called NullableListProperty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is passing three parameters and just pass one or the other:

```
public class ListProperty<TListItem, TValueStruct, TValueClass> 
where TValueStruct : struct
where TValueClass : class
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. The C# nullable syntax `T?` is (mostly) a shortcut for `System.Nullable<T>`. And `System.Nullable` does not allow reference types for `T`. That's why you cannot apply `?` to a (generic) type that is potentially a reference type. You can restrict `TValue` to `struct` however.

Or, you can write your own `Nullable` helper struct that allows reference types.

Comment: you are the first with insight into my real problem. I will have a look at a custom Nullable, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting them in different classes:

```
public abstract class ListProperty<TListItem, TValue> {
  public TValue Value { get; set; }
  ...
}

public class RefListProperty<TListItem, TValue> : 
  ListProperty<TListItem, TValue> where TValue : class {
}

public class ValListProperty<TListItem, TValue> : 
  ListProperty<TListItem, Nullable<TValue>> where TValue : struct {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and short: as you need to instantiate different versions at different places, why not

```
ListProperty<SomeListItemType, SomeReferenceType>
```

and

```
ListProperty<SomeOtherListItemType, SomeValueType?>
```

where appropriate? But maybe i've got something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but as your class stands now, you can use any type for `TValue`, including a nullable type:

```
new ListProperty<string, string>(someList1);    // reference type: string
new ListProperty<string, DateTime?>(someList2); // nullable value type: DateTime?
new ListProperty<string, DateTime>(someList3);  // non-null value type: DateTime
```

If you want to prevent the last use *only*, I think it's impossible with constraints on `TValue` in the class declaration. But you could make a check runtime by adding a static constructor like this:

```
static ListProperty()
{
  if (default(TValue) != null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Type argument must allow null", "TValue");
}
```